# R fails to start after moving Rprofile

Tags: r, rstudio, rprofile

I'm using R on a Mac. I tried moving my Rprofile file to a different location, but R didnt start. When I tried to put the Rprofile file back into its original location, I couldn't remember which folder exactly it came from.

My Rprofile file was located somewhere in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/...

Now R (and RStudio) fail to start, and R gives this error message:

```
Error: package 'grDevices' does not have a namespace

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0xa8000000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

RStudio gives the message:

```
The R session had a fatal error.

ERROR r error 4 (R code execution error) [errormsg=Error : package 'utils' does not have a namespace
]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error r::exec::evaluateString(const std::string &, SEXP *, sexp::Protect *) /Users/rstudio/rstudio/src/cpp/r/RExec.cpp:255
```

I'm assuming R cannot find the Rprofile file. How can I get R (and RStudio) to start again?

Comment: try this `R --vanilla`

Comment: @dickoa where do I put `R --vanilla`?

Comment: Type this command in your terminal.

Comment: R shouldn't need to rely on an Rprofile file to be able to start properly.  Did you recently upgrade R or any packages?

Comment: @dickoa R -- vanilla starts R in terminal as normal. However, the R application and RStudio still fail to start (and give same error messages).

Comment: @Dason no did not recently upgrade R or install any packages. The issue happened immediately after I moved the Rprofile file out from its original location.

Comment: Installing 3.0.0 seems to have solved problem (I was using 2.15.xx)

Comment: Glad you're up & running. Most likely your previous installation had a corrupted file somewhere.  You know the "Three R's of Software" : Retry, Reboot, Reinstall :-)

Answer (score 0):

I go this exact same error, which was a little irritating. For me it was that I was telling RStudio to use x64 (64 bit).

I had to uninstall R completely, start up Rstudio, it asked for the location of R

I installed bot 64 and 32 bit versions

Pointed RStudio to the newly installed R, but the 32 bit location this time. It started fine.

Done using RStudio 0.98.507 with R 3.1.0 [Windows 7 64Bit]